# Evaluate a $3\times3$ determinant.

Tags: determinant

Show that $$\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\1&b&b^2\\1&c&c^2\end{matrix}\right|=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$

Comment: You need to seriously edit your question to include (a) Mathjax formatting, (b) a little information as to the context of the problem and (c) your efforts in attempting this problem.

Comment: @manishkumar Welcome to MSE. You need to learn how to format math. There is a useful guide here http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation In the meantime I have edited your question. Let me know if that is not what you want.

Comment: Expand the determinant through the first column and notice that the $(1,1)$ minor $M_{1, 1}=(1)^1.1.(bc^{2}-b^{2}c)$ then find $M_{2, 1}$ and $M_{3, 1}$.

Comment: The determinant is zero (since two rows are equal) when $a=b$, $b=c$ or $c = a$. The determinant is also a polynomial of degree $2$ in each of $a,b,c$. This can be used to find the determinant up to a constant without explicitly computing it. The constant can be found by considering the diagonal contribution $1\cdot b\cdot c^2$.

Comment: This is a Vandermonde Matrix.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\1&b&b^2\\1&c&c^2\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\0&b-a&b^2-a^2\\0&c-a&c^2-a^2\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}b-a&b^2-a^2\\c-a&c^2-a^2\end{matrix}\right|=(b-a)(c-a)\left|\begin{matrix}1&b+a\\1&c+a\end{matrix}\right|=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b).$$

---

Alternatively, paving the way for a generalization,
$$\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\1&b&b^2\\1&c&c^2\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\0&b-a&b^2-a^2\\0&c-a&c^2-a^2\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\0&b-a&b^2-a^2\\0&c-a&c^2-a^2\end{matrix}\right|=(b-a)(c-a)\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\0&1&b+a\\0&1&c+a\end{matrix}\right|=(b-a)(c-a)\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\0&1&b+a\\0&0&c-b\end{matrix}\right|=(b-a)(c-a)(c-b)\left|\begin{matrix}1&a&a^2\\0&1&b+a\\0&0&1\end{matrix}\right|.$$

Comment: The most elegant approach, +1.

Comment: @Bacon Not going into comparisons but I already mentioned this approach in my answer and I do believe my approach is better.

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty It seems you did; however I disagree with you insofar as I think Yves' answer is more elegant than yours and why I upvoted his/her answer.

Comment: @bacon: I would rate as elegant an answer that is easy to understand, requires little computation and generalizes to higher order in an obvious way. Based on these criteria, my best choice is elsewhere on this page :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I love your arrogance! :-)

Comment: @Bacon: you are welcome.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "generalizes to higher order in an obvious way" this answer wins..."elegant an answer that is easy to understand, requires little computation" your answer below wins.

Answer (score 1):

Observe

1. The expression must be a homogeneous polynomial of degree at most $3$ as all terms involved are made of factors of degree $0+1+2$.
2. The expression cancels when two of the parameters are equal.

Then the expression must be of the form $$K(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$ for some constant $K$.

As the main diagonal generates the term $+bc^2$, by identification we must have $K=1$.

Comment: "As the main diagonal generates the term $+bc^2$, by identification we must have $K=1$" I don't get it...what I did was setting some values of $a,b,c$ and evaluating the determinant in both ways...are you doing something different?

Comment: Still I would like to know...

Comment: I do believe that your reasoning is quite correct...that makes your answer better than mine...+1

Answer (score 0):

Yes this determinant can be expanded row-wise or row operations $R_2=R_2-R_1$ and $R_3=R_3-R_1$ and then expanded...but there's a better way.

Clearly setting $a=b$ or $b=c$ or $a=c$ gives determinant as a multiple of $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$

Also the fact that determinant can at most have power 2 over $a$ , $b$ or $c$ gives that it is a constant times $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.

And the constant can be easily determined by setting $a=-1,b=0,c=1$ and evaluating the determinant and the expression.

Hope this helps.